# Remove phone country code using Regex in R

Tags: r, regex, string, replace

I am trying to clean up a column of phone numbers in a df.

I would like to remove the country code (254) from the start of the phone number. Occasionally there are repeats of this country code (254254) and occasionally the phone number itself is truncated (2540). I do not want to remove any instances of 254 which occur within the number itself. I have tried a range of solutions, including

```
name <- c('James','Peter','Jolie', 'Freddy')
phoneNumber <- c("254703162522", "254254342544942", "2540", "728124572")
df <- data.frame(name, phoneNumber)

df$phoneNumber <- df$phoneNumber %>% str_replace_all('/254{1,2}/', '')
```

and

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(str_replace(., '/254{1,2}/', '')))
```

But nothing I do seems to actually change the values. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: You don't need JS-style `/regexdelimiters/` with the slashes in R.

Comment: Also, you may use `gsub("\\G254", "", ., perl=TRUE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does this meet your needs?

```
df %>% 
  mutate(phoneNumber_new = str_remove_all(phoneNumber, '^(254)+'))
```

Explanation: `^` indicates the start of a string and the `+` repeats the prior string.

Comment: Yes it does! Could you explain why mine wasn't working

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you tried to acheive with the slashes, tbh. The curlys are okay, yet the plus is more generic. However, if you would only want to remove it if the string occurs once or twice, you could be more explicit. [This](http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/grepl.php) is my go-to wbsite regarding regexes in R

Comment: This would actually change a number starting with e.g. `22200000`, because of your brackets. You want parentheses for grouping.

Comment: `"^(254){1,2}"` is the pattern I'd use, and `"^(254)+"` if we were certain that there were never 254 patterns to be kept (like triple duplication)

Comment: Indeed!, my mistake. Thanks Brian. I adapt the answer